# Why is Qt recognizing neither my header files, nor my library files?

Tags: c++, qt, header-files

[image: PRO File]
The above is my PRO file. There is a PvAPI.lib, an ImageLib.lib, and a PvApi.h, an ImageLib.h file, and a StdAfx.h file. The latter three are in the INCLUDEPATH paths and the library locations are given as follows under LIBS.

However, the compiler still doesn't seem to recognize the first header file that's brought up. Any reason as to why? Perhaps I am declaring the paths incorrectly?

Issues:

> C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\GO TO
>   HELL\HardTrigger\USERINTERFACE-THINGS\UserInterface-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug....\HardTrigger.cpp:62: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'PvApi.h': No such file or
>   directory

Comment: QMake has issues with spaces in paths. Better use paths without spaces. (Or a build system like cmake)

Comment: Do the INCLUDEPATH and LIB lines seem fine though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PvApi.h seems to be in "somefolder\inc-pc", while INCLUDEPATH contains "somefolder\inc-pc\include"